# Specify schema for doing liquibase diff in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, ant, liquibase

I'm trying to do a liquibase diff in Oracle using an ant script.

Here's the snippet that preforms the diff

```
<target name="diff-database">
    <diffDatabaseToChangeLog
        driver=${db.driver}"
        url="${db.url}"
        username="${db.username}"
        password="${db.password}"

        referenceUrl="jdbc:oracle:thin@hostname:port:sid"
        referenceUsername="user1"
        referencePassword="password1"

        outputFile="changelog.xml"
        classpathref="tools.class.path"
    </diffDatabaseToChangeLog>
</target>
```

Here's the issue.

- The two databases I need to compare are both Oracle.
- For the referenceDB I need access to the tables under a certain user, call it user2, but login for user2 is disabled on the server I need to run this from.
- Luckily I have access to the referenceDB under another user, call it user1, and that user has the privilege "SELECT ANY TABLE".  So I should be able to access the tables for user2 with user1.

So given all of that information, how do I specify that I want to use user2's tables as the reference DB?

I've look at [this page](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/ant/index.html), but haven't found anything that solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be referenceDefaultSchemaName parameter (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_diff.html), but according to https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2364 there could be some issues (I've not triedit myself).

Comment: That worked thanks!  I don't know why it wasn't included in this page.  http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/ant/index.html

Comment: cool. Could be added here: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase.github.com/blob/master/documentation/ant/index.md :)